# Weak operator topology and matrix representation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

For simplicity let $H$ be the separable Hilbert space and $(e_i)_i$ be a fixed orthonormal basis. Weak operator topology on $B(H)$ is usually defined using seminorms $|(Tu,v)|$ where $u,v$ are vectors in $H$. Let us denote $\mathcal{T}$ the topology induced by the seminorms $|(Te_i,e_j)|$. I believe this is also the topology induced by all $|(Tu,v)|$ where $u,v$ are finite linear combination of $e_i$'s. What is the relation between $\mathcal{T}$ and WOT? Do they agree on norm bounded sets? I guess yes because

$||(Tu,v)|-|(Tu_0,v_0)||\leq|(Tu,v)-(Tu_0,v_0)|=|(Tu-Tu_0,v)+(Tu_0,v-v_0)|$

$\leq||T||\cdot||u-u_0||\cdot||v||+||T||\cdot||u_0||\cdot||v-v_0||$

So for any fixed $u,v$ and $\epsilon>0$, if $u_0,v_0\in \text{span}\{e_i\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are close enough to $u,v$ and there is a uniform bound on $||T||$, then $|(Tu_0,v_0)|\leq \epsilon$ implies $|(Tu,v)|\leq 2\epsilon$.

Now since we fix a basis $(e_i)_i$ we can regard operators as infinite matrices and $(Te_i,e_j)$ is the $j,i$-th entry. Therefore if the above calculation is correct then on bounded sets WOT can be viewed as “entrywise convergence topology”. This looks more comfortable and intuitive for me, <strike>for example it becomes even clearer that unit ball is compact because we can view it as a subspace of $[-1,1]^{\mathbb{N}^2}$</strike> (I found that I don't know how to argue it is a closed subspace without using the fact that it is same as WOT). Similarly strong operator topology may be viewed as “columnwise convergence topology”.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  Although $\mathcal T$ coincides with the WOT on bounded sets, as observed by the OP, these topologies
do not coincide over the whole of
$B(H)$.

One very nice point of view from which to understand this question is the theory of duality.  Suppose $B$ is a complex
vector space (I am using the letter $B$ here because the application will be for $B=B(H)$).   Suppose also we are given
a set   $\Phi $  of linear functionals on $B$.

One may then define a topology $\mathcal T$ on $B$ using the seminorms
$$
  T\in B\mapsto |\varphi (T)|\in \mathbb R,
  $$
for every $\varphi $ in $\Phi $.

It is evident that every $\varphi $ in $\Phi $ is $\mathcal T$-continuous and hence also every linear combination of functionals in
$\Phi $.

The key fact is that nothing else is continuous!  In other words, the topological dual of $(B,\mathcal T)$ is precisely
the linear span of $\Phi $ within the algebraic dual of $B$.

Taking $B=B(H)$ and $\Phi $ the set of linear functionals of the form
$$
  T\in B(H)\mapsto \langle Te_i, e_j\rangle ,
  \tag{1}
  $$
we may ask whether or not a linear  functional of the form
$$
  T\in B(H)\mapsto \langle Tu, v\rangle ,
  \tag {2}
  $$
is $\mathcal T$-continuous,  for given vectors $u$ and $v$ in $H$.

The answer will be negative if $u$ and $v$ are
infinite linear combinations of basis elements since one may easily prove that  (2) is not a *finite* linear combination
of functionals as in (1).

Comment: I am aware that they don't agree on the whole $B(H)$...Just want to be certain that they agree on bounded sets since it does not seem to be mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Well, then I guess I misunderstood your question.  But again, yes, you are correct about the two  topologies coinciding on bounded sets.